# Does rails load associated relation each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

E.g. I have a model called `Book` which `belongs_to` model `Shelf` with fields `:bookcase` and `:number`.

I wonder, if I call to `book.shelf.bookcase` and then later to `book.shelf.number` does Rails actually load corresponding `shelf` each time? Or does it cache `book.shelf` somewhere? Shouldn't I make a new variable `shelf = book.shelf` and use `shelf.bookcase` and `shelf.number` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will cache association information, so you get whatever is in the cache when you access it. It does not reload it from the database each time.

There are cases when you do want a reload from the database, in which case the following syntax is used:

```
book.shelf(true).number
```

See section 3.1 in [A Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).